# Проблемы с кодировками

Tags: php, html, кодировка

Сам сайт в кодировке utf-8.
в нтаксесе прописана дефолтная кодировка и в хедере страницы.
этот сайт загружает страницу из инета и берет из ответа заголовка кодировку, например это 1251. потом с помощью nokogiri.php - парсит title и h1 со страницы. ну и выводит на странице сайта.
Дак вот как так вышло что если сайт в win1251 он выводит его на странице хорошо.
а если спарсил сайт в utf8 - вывело кракозябры
Раньше использовал simple_html_dom.php было вроде все хорошо с кодировкой, но он ужасно медленый и памяти жрет дофига.

Не могу понять почему кодировка так себя ведет?!

итак, понял, что накогири использует

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8' );
```

вот тут я попытался руками поменять UTF-8 на windows-1251
не помогло! самое интересное что если сайт в windows-1251 т овсе ок, а если UTF-8 то все - провал! вот такой:

> ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸ÑÐ° Ð¾Ñ Ð²Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð²,
>   Ð±Ð¾ÑÑÐ±Ð° Ñ Ð²Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ°Ð¼Ð¸,
>   Ð¶Ð¸Ð·Ð½Ñ Ð±ÐµÐ·
>   ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑÑÑÐµÑÐ½ÑÑ
>   Ð²Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð²

ЕЩЕ РАЗ уточняю проблему. мой сайт загружает чужие/другие страницы из инета, выдергивает заголовки, берет кодировку из ответа сервера, и уже преобразовывает вытащенную инфу в utf8, поэтому я не могу жостко прописать какие то преобразования, нужно именно универсально чтобы было.

DOMDocument почему то корректно загружает страницы именно на win1251, хотя мой то сайт на utf8 (и сайт и база куда он данные записывает) если страница была на utf8 то в базу крокозябры попадают (как сказал комментатор уже в iso8859-1 кодировке)

Comment: Ваши кракозябры в кодировке **iso8859-1**. Если проблема только с одной строкой, то можно просто:

    $str = 'ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸ÑÐ° Ð¾Ñ Ð²Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð², Ð±Ð¾ÑÑÐ±Ð° Ñ Ð²Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ°Ð¼Ð¸, Ð¶Ð¸Ð·Ð½Ñ Ð±ÐµÐ· ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑÑÑÐµÑÐ½ÑÑ Ð²Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ¾Ð²';
    echo iconv('utf-8','iso8859-1',$str); // Защита от вирусов, борьба с вирусами, жизнь без компьютерных вирусов

Comment: а парсер у вас на винде ? проверьте что default_charset в php.ini не выставлен в cp1251 тут вот еще по теме http://devzone.zend.com/1538/php-dom-xml-extension-encoding-processing/

Comment: это данные с сервера, на sweb хостинге

Comment: @armenka, вы не можете четко сказать какая операционка у вас на той машине где запускается этот парсер ? Мне лично не важно как ваш хостер называется.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй создать файл .htaccess и написать в нем `AddCharset UTF-8`

Comment: Тогда уж лучше:

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может возникать из-за отсутствующего мета-тега с кодировкой. Мне, в свое время, помогло на первый взгляд странное, но действенное решение:

```
$response = str_replace('<head>', '<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">', $response);
```

Answer (score -2):

Сталкивался с таким - открой NotePad++ - кодировка -> преобразовать в (UTF-8) и тогда будет тебе русский язык отображать )

Comment: нет не катит. тут именно проблема в new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8' ); перекодировки файлов не помогают.

Answer (score -2):

Если сервак на линуксе, то открой код в ноутпаде и преобразуйте кодировку в UTF-8 без BOM.

Answer (score -4):

попробуйте ввести не windows-1251 а  cp1251 должно сработать.
а вообще с utf-8 почти всегда возникают проблемы тем-более что подвидов у utf-8 очень много а русский поддерживают единицы. не морочте себе голову зделайте сайт в windows-1251 и всё будет нормально, в конечном итоге это не целесообразно в плане производительности переводить целые страницы да и ещё боятся за каждый новый подключенный документ. "Заработает или нет?"

Comment: тоесть? у меня каждый раз страницы разные загружаются, это я для примера привел что загружаю страницу в 1251 бывает в koi8 или еще какой грузится, у меня типа сайта - парсера. это поможет? щас буду проверять

Comment: Блин! забыл добавить то. не помогло то для сайта в UTF8 а сайты на windows-1251 загружаются нормально - парадокс, я щас не могу нормально загрузить страницу именно в utf8, сам сайт тоже в utf8

Comment: @vano, очень глупый ответ. " utf-8 почти всегда возникают проблемы" - неправда, "подвидов у utf-8 очень много" - неправда, utf-8 один, "русский поддерживают единицы" - бред.

Comment: Спасибо за критику dzhioev действительно неправ признаю. А теперь armenka попробуйте использовать функцию utf8_encode().

Comment: бред это не использовать в 21м веке UTF8